# Can I add the URL from a Facebook status update to a Google Spreadsheet with IFTTT

Tags: facebook, google-sheets, if-this-then-that

Would it be possible to save the actual URL where you can find the individual post to a new row in a Google Spreadsheet from Facebook to Google Drive Spreadsheets?

(You can get to the FB status URL by clicking the time/date). A URL could be:
`https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102890573589151?pnref=story`
(Zuckerberg's latest non-photo post).

I know there is an IFTTT recipe to add the actual content of a Facebook status update to a new row in a Google Spreadsheet including name poster and date added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The only ingredients for a normal Facebook status update are "UpdatedAt", "Message", and "From".

A link status update does offer a "Link" ingredient, but that's the URL of the link you're posting, not the link to your status message.